# Updating checkboxes with php and mysqli

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Objective: Allow user to choose items from available list of checkboxes and have the id attached update the DB. After $_POST, the chosen items are checked.

Issues: Once form is submitted, the PREVIOUS set of checked boxes are returned and not the current. If form is submitted again without changing anything, the NEW set of checked boxes are now available. Basically, the new values will only be shown after the submit btn has been pressed twice.

Code:
Function querying the DB to populate the form with checkboxes...

```
function chCheck($conn){
$sql = "Select CHEESE, ID, OnMenu from CheeseSelections";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {   
            if ($row['OnMenu']==="True"){
                $str =  "<input type='checkbox' name='chList[]' value='".$row['ID']."' id='".$row['CHEESE']."' checked/>";
                $str .= "<label for ='".$row['CHEESE']."'>".$row['CHEESE']."</label>";
                $str .= " <a href=\"#\">view/edit item</a><br />";  
                echo $str;
                }
            elseif ($row['OnMenu']==="False"){
                $str =  "<input type='checkbox' name='chList[]' value='".$row['ID']."' id='".$row['CHEESE'];
                $str .= "/> <label for ='".$row['CHEESE']."'>".$row['CHEESE']."</label>";
                $str .= " <a href=\"#\">view/edit item</a><br />";  
                echo $str;
                }
        }
```

}

HTML

```
 <form name="chCheck" method="post" action="">
        <?php chCheck($conn); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Selections"></br>  
    </form>
```

$_POST

```
if ($_POST) 
    {
        $ids = $_POST['chList'];

                $sql = "UPDATE CheeseSelections SET CheeseSelections.OnMenu = \"False\";";
        foreach($ids as $items){        
                $sql .= "UPDATE CheeseSelections SET CheeseSelections.OnMenu = \"True\" WHERE CheeseSelections.ID IN (".$items."); ";
                    }       
        //echo $sql;

        mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $conn->affected_rows);

        printf("Error Code: %d\n", $conn->errno);
    }
```

Logic: When submitted, the entire column of "OnMenu" is set to "False". The collected ID's from the $_POST is then set to "True". This unsets and then resets the column. Is this logic sound? What should I be doing differently?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the code to update the database working correctly? Is it called before you generate the HTML for the form?

Comment: @andrewsi - Yes, the query works in the database. The way the page is formatted reflects the order above. The checkbox population function is before the html tag, the form is inside the html and the $_POST is located before the closing html tag.

Comment: andrewsi -  your answer makes sense & @Revent - your answer is informative and educational. However, when I do place the $_POST processing at the top of the script, above or below the function script, I receive a "function fetch_assoc() on a non-object" error for the chCheck() function.

Comment: You don't explicitly close your connection somewhere, do you?

Comment: No. I do not close the connection.

Comment: Could you add a little extra debugging into the top of the chCheck function? A few calls to `$conn->error` should do the trick, I think.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things I would do differently. First, as a best practice, avoid duplicating your input boxes when the only difference is the checked status. Currently you would have to make a change in two places if you decide to make a change.

```
function chCheck($conn)
{
    $sql = "Select CHEESE, ID, OnMenu from CheeseSelections";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {   
        $selected = ($row['OnMenu'] === "True" ? ' checked="checked"' : '');
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chList[]" value="'.$row['ID'].'" id="'.$row['CHEESE'].'"'.$selected.' /><label for="'.$row['CHEESE'].'">'.htmlentities($row['CHEESE']).'</label> <a href="#">view/edit item</a><br />';               
    }
}
```

Secondly, HTML checkboxes don't post a value when unchecked like radio buttons do. On POST I would clear all the values first (set all database values to False as you are doing), then loop through the posted values, put them into an array and then call a single query to set those to True.

```
$item_ids = array();
foreach ($ids as $item)
    $item_ids[] = intval($item);  // to prevent $_POST data type tampering

$sql .= "UPDATE CheeseSelections SET CheeseSelections.OnMenu = 'True' WHERE CheeseSelections.ID IN (".implode(",",$item_ids)."); ";
```

Make sure that your $_POST handling code is at the top of your script above your function call as well. That could possibly be the cause of the behavior you are seeing.

I would also avoid storing a boolean value as text, so I would use a TinyInt(1) data type and set it to either 0 or 1, rather than use text values of 'True' and 'False'. It's just more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your program's logic.

You're generating the HTML for the form, then running the SQL updates at the end. When a user clicks submit and the next page is created, the database query returns their existing choices, and generates the HTML accordingly. Finally, the $_POST is processed, and the database updates - so it's not updating until the page is already generated.

Try moving your whole `$_POST` if statement to before your call to `chCheck()`